# Getting http status code from file_get_contents inside helper function

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a custom helper function (`Codeigniter 3`) I made that builds a url, passes that url to the `file_get_contents()` function and then wraps all that into the `json_decode()` function and returns it to my `controller` which loads the `view` to be processed.  Here is the function:

```
function get_json($zipcode) {
    $api_key = KEY;
    $url = 'https://example.com/request.json?api_key=' . $api_key . '&address=' . $zipcode;

    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    }
```

I'm calling this in my controller here:

```
$this->load->helper('functions_helper');
$data['json'] =  get_json($data['zipcode']);
```

Then I'm building a table in my `view` based on the returned data:

```
<?php if (isset($json)) : ?>
    <?php if ($json['metadata']['resultset']['count'] == 0 || http_response_code() == 400): //response code doesn't work ?>

        <div class="inline-block">
            <h3>We apologize but we couldn't locate any results in your area.</h3>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <!-- table elements -->
        </table>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This works as long as my json api source is up and reliable.  However if I pass a zipcode value that isn't an actual zipcode, the api returns the following, with an http status code of 400:

```
{
   "inputs": {
      "address": "00607"
   },
   "metadata": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resultset": {
         "count": 0
      }
   },
   "status": 400,
   "errors": [
      "Unable to geocode address: 00607"
   ]
}
```

This breaks my page and I get a php error at the top `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`, even if I try and get the status from the returned json `json['status']`

Also if the json source is down (http status code 500) I get the same.

My question is how can I check the status code in my function before passing it to my page?  I tried checking before building my table in the page above, but of course my page gives a status code 200 which is that status of the `view` the `controller` built, and not the status of the actual json results.

Comment: Use curl to retrieve the url, this gives you more control and allows you to check the status code before you try to parse the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rick suggested in the comments you should use curl.

```
function get_json($zipcode) {
    $api_key = KEY;
    $url = 'https://example.com/request.json?api_key=' . $api_key . '&address=' . $zipcode;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = (int) curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($http_code == 200) {
        return json_decode($result, true);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```